# How to input a read value when calling a shell script

Tags: bash, shell

Let say I have this line in a shell script in unix:

```
read -n 1
```

It will prompt the user to get value but is there a way to call the script so it takes the input as argument instead?

Like this for example:

```
myscript.sh "M"
```

I want to call the script from a build engine so it cannot answer with keyboard input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use argument values in shell script you can pass the argument with the script and then refer them using $1, $2, $3 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Here Strings` in `bash`:

```
myscript.sh <<< "M"
```

Or use pipeline:

```
echo "M" | myscript.sh
```

[Here string documentation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html)

Comment: I've been looking for ages for that, what are the keywords we can use?

Comment: It shows up under `Here Strings` section in `man bash`. Or you can check link I have added in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this with some frequency:

```
hello() {  read -n1 CHAR;  echo $CHAR; }
echo world | hello
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
myscript.sh $(read -n 1)
```

?